# How to calculate age in years/month/days in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to calculate age with birth day and current day. result should be "years-month-day".How can i do ? Please help.

i'm try this but not be great

DateDiff(“yyyy”,birthday,currentday)

if current date is 20/05/2015  and birth date is 1/06/1991, result = 24 but it should be 23 years 5 month 19 days

Comment: what date is 20/05/15?

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy May 20 to everyone not in the United States

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy that is current date

Comment: This formula appears to work well but I came across an anomaly with the date 29/05/1977; the formula returned 40 Years 11 Months 28 days
instead of 40 Years 10 Months 28 days . Seems to work fine with other dates in my test data. There is obviously a reason for this but I’ve not had time to research this further. Just thought I’d let you know.

Answer (score 2):

```
If (Not(isNull({@birthdate}))) Then
ToText(int(DateDiff('d',{@birthdate},CurrentDate())/365.25),0)+' Years '+
ToText(int(remainder(DateDiff('d',{@birthdate},CurrentDate()),365.25)/30),0)+' Months '+
If day(CurrentDate()) < Day({@birthdate}) Then
ToText(day(dateserial(year({@birthdate}), Month({@birthdate})+1,1-1)) - Day({@birthdate}) + Day(CurrentDate()),0) + ' days'
Else
 ToText(day(CurrentDate()) - day({@birthdate}),0) + ' days'
```

No perfect but works nicely.. here is an article to read that might help as well for 
[calculating birthdays](http://www.kenhamady.com/formulas/form06.shtml)

Comment: Very good and simple example but it could have been much better if there was added some functionality to insert an (And or &) before days in order to make it look more professional, and display "days" only if there were more than one day and only "day" in case of 1 day.

Comment: @Omer .. Thanks for your comment... I agree with your opinion regarding a few tweaks for a more professional output however my goal was to give the OP functionality that works.